# Port [origin].concat(ray(nextStep)) from JavaScript to Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, concatenation, porting, raycasting

I am porting a raycaster from JavaScript to Swift and am having some difficulty understanding what the following line is doing:

```
[origin].concat(ray(nextStep))
```

Here is the full function:

```
function ray(origin) {
    var stepX = step(sin, cos, origin.x, origin.y);
    var stepY = step(cos, sin, origin.y, origin.x, true);
    var nextStep = stepX.length2 < stepY.length2 ? inspect(stepX, 1, 0, origin.distance, stepX.y) : inspect(stepY, 0, 1, origin.distance, stepY.x);

    if (nextStep.distance > range) return [origin];
    return [origin].concat(ray(nextStep));
}
```

Could someone help me with what the [] brackets symbolize in this case and what the concat will do in this case?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. [`Array.prototype.concat`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.4) returns a new array whose elements are the arguments if they aren't arrays, or the items inside them if they are arrays.

If `ray(nextStep)` is not an array, it will be equivalent to

```js
[orgin, ray(nextStep)]
```

If `ray(nextStep)` is an array, it will be equivalent to

```js
[orgin, ...ray(nextStep)]
```

For example,

```js
[1,2,3].concat(4, [5,6], 7); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```